# Setting a cookie from a GET param to uniquely identify mobile users

Tags: android, iphone, ruby-on-rails, cookies

I need to uniquely identify mobile devices on my rails app without user registration.

They will be using a mobile app with an embedded with the default url hardcoded  into the app.
I'm thinking of doing

domain.com?uniqueid=[UniqueDeviceIdentifier usingLocalMethods]

and saving that in the session cookie so as the user loads subsequent pages through links from the index I can track that unique id.

Is there a much better way of handling this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about your app, but a couple of things come to mind...

- If you can send it as a HTTP header, that would hide it from the user, assuming it's going to launch their phone's browser.
- Don't send them to the root of your site.  Send them to say `domain.com/mobile-launcher?uniqueid=....` This way you've got a dedicated place to handle your logic and can redirect them to the homepage.

Comment: Solid tips. Will try HTTP header tomorrow and see how it works.