# How do i get a user phone serial number or ip number with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Am building a hybrid app with html, css and Javascript, I want the app to run only on my phone, I want to be able to use Javascript to get my ip number or serial number, if it matches the number already stored in a variable, then it will allow me to acess the app. Thanks

Comment: Serial number, not possible. Would be a security issue. IP, yes that you can do. Search for it. Tons of resources.

Comment: You should be posting your progress more so than just asking for the answer, this site is designed to help you fix code, rather than fully write your code for you.

Comment: I think he is asking how can he identify a device from JS i think that is agood valid question.

Comment: If that’s true then dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585082/can-i-uniquely-identify-a-mobile-device-from-a-website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the phone number, serial id from the phone using JS code. You can use a wrapper such as [phonegap](https://phonegap.com/) which would allow you to convert your js html app into a native app. There api might let you do something close you would need to check the docs.

https://phonegap.com/

From JS you can't get the IP of the phone, to get the IP from JS you could either talk to your own server and get the IP or use for example a free [GEO ip api](http://ip-api.com/docs/api:json) which would allow you to call from the client JS code as follows:

Here is such a free api

http://ip-api.com/docs/api:json

This would return the device IP in json along with some geo results.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <title>IP-API.com Geo Location Demo</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="GeoResults"></table>
        <script>
        $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?", function(data) {
            var table_body = "";
            $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                table_body += "<tr><td>" + k + "</td><td><b>" + v + "</b></td></tr>";
            });
            $("#GeoResults").html(table_body);
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The last option would be to create your own uuid and store that as a cookie or if your using JS in [local storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). Then you could read that ID back when your app is run and use it to id the device.

```
function generateUUID() {
    var d = new Date().getTime();
    var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
        var r = (d + Math.random()*16)%16 | 0;
        d = Math.floor(d/16);
        return (c=='x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8)).toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
};
```

You can read how to store in in the device local storage and retreive it here:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp